# Polymer button flicker on navigating away from page

Tags: html, angular, polymer, page-refresh

I have an html page with polymer elements, which uses angular. I have a paper-toolbar. Page 1 has a delete button on this as

```
<paper-icon-button title="Delete" icon="delete"....>
```

There is some text on this page which links to Page 2

```
<a  href="#/page2/{id}">{{status}</a>
```

Clicking on the link takes you to Page 2. The Page 2 controller loads some data using ajax calls, and does some processing. However, there is a small flicker of only the delete button from the previous page which shows on Page 2. It shows up for a second, and the user can incorrectly invoke the delete function.

Why does only this button show up Page 2? Is there any way to mitigate this?

Thank you in advance